Windows installation failed and "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Status" is missing
I formatted my notebook and installed Windows, but I got the error "The computer restarted unexpectedly or encountered an unexpected error. Windows installation cannot be proceed. To install Windows, click 'ok' to restart the computer, and then restart the installation". I've tried installing again, both Windows 10 and 11, and I always get the same error.
I saw the suggestion to change HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Status\ChildCompletion but the Status folder is always missing from the Setup folder.
Another suggestion was to run msoobe.exe from the command prompt, but I've tried that and nothing happens.
Any ideas on how I can finish the installation?
One thing to note is that my notebook's battery is dead, but I've seen indications that this wouldn't be the cause of the problem.
Another thing is that I used Rufus to create my installation media.

Perhaps the simplest to check first: Have you tried recreating the boot/installation media? Or have you used a different tool to create the media? I like Rufus, but for basic installs, Microsoft's own tool is pretty simple, and for certain special cases, I'm aware that other tools are recommended besides Rufus.

It might be the dead battery: during Windows installation reboot, all drives and fans seem to run at max for a few seconds, perhaps overloading the laptop PS. Try another OS as a test, e.g., Ubuntu, which can be installed in less than 1/2 hour.

Thanks for the tip @music2myear. I will give a try to Microsoft's own tool although I believe the media is not the problem, just used it to install Windows in 4 other PCs.

Nice tip @DrMoishePippik. I will try this test. But before I will try using a more powerful PS from a newer notebook.
